# How to load Iris dataset into a data frame?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I need to Load Iris dataset into a data frame. Check out and print the information of this dataset. and then Using .describe() method, check the descriptive statistics of the data as well.
I'm not quite sure what I did is right.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
print(df.info())
print(df.describe())
```

Comment: What do you get as output, and what did you expect to get as output instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.style` to print your dataframe as a table in pandas (don't but the command in `print`)

Or you use `display(df)`

If you want to use `df.info()` and `df.describe()` , so get them out the `print()` command.